INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id when recall approval process
I have an approval process on my FiscalForm__c object. The Approval process set allow submitter to recall the approval process.
On the FiscalForm has 2 user fields, one field for Submitter and the other is Owner.
I'm login as Submitter to submit the request. But as requirement end user want the Owner can recall the FiscalForm too. So I have follow the guideline in here:
https://jayakrishnasfdc.wordpress.com/2021/04/17/recall-an-approval-process-step-using-apex-or-lightning-flow-in-salesforce/
However, when I login as the Owner to Recall the approval process I got "INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id".
I have set access to the Invocable class for all users, the Apex I set is is without sharing class.
Is there anything that I'm missing?

The root cause of this is, user should have Edit access to ProcessInstanceWorkItems to be able to Recall it.
